# pandas combine a criteria with multiple rows to a comma dilimeted column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I'm trying to combine all URL fields returned by an id in the same DF into a comma delimitted field. What I can't figure out is why my assign is not working and my for loop is..

The table looks like as follows:

| Ref | Option1_Ref | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,3,4 | /path1 |
| 2 | 1,4,5 | /path2 |
| 3 | 1,6 | /path3 |
| 4 | 1,5 | /path4 |
| 4 | 2,5 | /path5 |
| 5 | 3,1 | /path6 |
| 7 | 2,5 | /path7 |

using assign :

`df=df.assign(options_url1=df.loc[df['Ref'].isin(df["Option1_Ref"].str.split(',')),['URL','Ref']].drop_duplicates('Ref')['URL'].str.join(','))`

This is just returning an empty column.

for loop:

`for x in df.index: df.loc[x,'options_url1']=','.join(df.loc[df['Ref'].isin(df.loc[x,"Option1_Ref"].split(',')),['URL','Ref']].drop_duplicates('Ref')['URL'].array)`

This is working as expected

I'm expecting:

| Ref | Option1_Ref | URL | options_url1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2,3,4 | /path1 | /path2,/path3,/path4 |
| 2 | 1,4,5 | /path2 | /path1,/path4,/path6 |
| 3 | 1,6 | /path3 | /path1 |
| 4 | 1,5 | /path4 | /path1,/path6 |
| 4 | 2,5 | /path5 | /path2,/path6 |
| 5 | 3,1 | /path6 | /path1,/path3 |
| 7 | 2,5 | /path5 | /path2,/path6 |

Comment: Is there always a match between the values in `Option1_Ref` and those in `Ref`? If not, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Series` by remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), convert `Ref` to strings and map splitted values with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), last aggregate `join`:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('Ref').astype({'Ref':str}).set_index('Ref')['URL']

df['options_url1'] = (df["Option1_Ref"].str.split(',').explode().map(s).dropna()
                                       .groupby(level=0).agg(','.join))
print (df)
   Ref Option1_Ref     URL          options_url1
0    1       2,3,4  /path1  /path2,/path3,/path4
1    2       1,4,5  /path2         /path1,/path4
2    3           1  /path3                /path1
3    4         1,5  /path4                /path1
4    6         2,5  /path5                /path2
```

Or use list comprhension for mapping and `join`, if possible some values not exist add `if` statement:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates('Ref').astype({'Ref':str}).set_index('Ref')['URL']

df['options_url1'] = [','.join(s.get(y) for y in x.split(',') if y in s)
                      for x in df["Option1_Ref"]]
print (df)
   Ref Option1_Ref     URL          options_url1
0    1       2,3,4  /path1  /path2,/path3,/path4
1    2       1,4,5  /path2         /path1,/path4
2    3           1  /path3                /path1
3    4         1,5  /path4                /path1
4    6         2,5  /path5                /path2
```

Comment: Thanks.
I tried this I get "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found" , note that 'Option1_Ref' can be null. There is also a possibility that Ref doesn't exist (meaning if Options_Ref = 1,2,4,6 , then 6 may not exist)... URL contains unique values.

Comment: @Mafiname - both solutions was changed.

Comment: These both work as well, the dictionary solution by @mozway seems to be faster. I still need to double check the data for all.  Thank you for both solutions.

Comment: @Mafiname - yop, if no match ouput is different.

Comment: Yes correct, this takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a dictionary, then use a regex with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
d = df.astype(str).set_index('Ref')['URL'].to_dict()

df['options_url1'] = (df['Option1_Ref']
                      .str.replace('[^,]+', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), m.group()),
                                   regex=True)
                     )
```

Output:

```
   Ref Option1_Ref     URL          options_url1
0    1       2,3,4  /path1  /path2,/path3,/path5
1    2       1,4,5  /path2  /path1,/path5,/path6
2    3           1  /path3                /path1
3    4         1,5  /path4         /path1,/path6
4    4         2,5  /path5         /path2,/path6
5    5         3,1  /path6         /path3,/path1
```

Comment: I think this works well. thank you. I will review the data and let you know.

Comment: @Mafiname you're welcome. Note that in case of no match I leave the value unchanged, but you can tweak that easily. Please update the example in the question if this is a possibility to make the desired behavior explicit.

Comment: I have updated the table to include Ref to '6' which wont get a match, in this case we should remove the path in options_url1... see line with Ref=3

Comment: to highlight no match I can add something like:

d = bigc.astype(str).set_index('SKU_Ref')['Product URL'].to_dict()

bigc['test field'] = (bigc['Option1_skus'].str.replace('[^,]+', lambda m: d.get(m.group(), "NO URL FOUND"),regex=True))